# Installing mysql-server showing error. Unmet dependencies:

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dpkg, mysql

I am trying to install `mysql-server` on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`. But I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04)
                    Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I found various answers online with very similar questions but none has any working answers. I tried so many commands in the terminal from answers I found but none worked and I'm mentioning here a few.

> ```
> sudo apt --fix-broken install 
> sudo apt reinstall
> sudo dpkg --configure --force-overwrite -a
> sudo apt-get clean
> sudo dpkg --configure -a
> sudo apt purge mysql-server
> sudo apt purge libmysqlclient21 
> sudo dpkg-i ~/Downloads/mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb 
> sudo dpkg -i mysql-{common,community-client,client,community-server,server)_*.deb
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> sudo apt-get install mysql-server
> ```

And in almost every one of them I get an Error. Not the same error for all. But the errors don't stop.

I found a solution which says to install `aptitude` or `synaptic package manager` to fix these. But to install those the `apt-get install` gives an error every single time.

Recommended by [nobody](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326298/installing-mysql-server-showing-error-unmet-dependencies?noredirect=1#comment2260915_1326298) I tried `apt-cache policy  mysql-server` and I got this output:

```
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04
  Version table:
     8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04 500
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal/mysql-8.0 amd64 Packages
     8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://qa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://qa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
     8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://qa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://qa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: The guide to using the MySQL APT repo https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

Comment: `apt-cache policy  mysql-server `

Comment: @DaveStokes Yes, I used that guide earlier. And I still couldn't solve it.

Comment: @nobody I entered this I and I got this output:

"mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04
  Version table:
     8.0.23-1ubuntu20.04 500
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal/mysql-8.0 amd64 Packages
     8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://qa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://qa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        ..."
And some more which I can't fit in this word limit It would be helpful to know what to do next?

Comment: @user535733 Would you please tell me how do I clean up all packages from non-Ubuntu sources? And install the compatible? Thanks

Comment: I actually solved it. The problem was when I did `apt install mysql-common` is showed `Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins...` and when I `apt install mysql-community-client-plugins` it showed `Depends: mysql-common...` so I installed both packages in a single command like `apt install mysql-community-client-plugins mysql-common` and it worked. Now I am able to install `mysql-server` and `mysql` works fine. Anyway Thanks.

Comment: I have tried with this link [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169028/mysql-server-cant-install-on-linux/66026366#66026366). It works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(SOLVED)

I realized the problem. When I tried installing both `mysql-common` and `mysql-community-client-plugins` individually it showed that the other one was not installed and is required. Meaning when I tried `sudo apt install mysql-common` it showed

> `Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins`

and vice versa.

Therefore, I installed both on a single command like

> `sudo apt install mysql-community-client-plugins mysql-common`

and both installed successfully. I installed `mysql-server` later, that too installed successfully and `mysql` is working well.